# Reset password of an unlocked LUKS encrypted drive

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, disk-encryption, luks

I have a machine running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS, with an encrypted drive using LUKS encryption.

The machine is running and the drive is unlocked. However, I forgot the passphrase to the drive.

I tried running the following command to add a new passphrase:

```
$ cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/nvme0n1p3
Enter any existing passphrase:
```

however, I need to know the existing passphrase in order to do this.

Is there a way to add a new passphrase without knowing the existing one?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't add a passphrase without an existing one. You may be able to do a memory dump and grab the encryption key directly from your system's memory as an alternative.

Comment: I think this can only be done on older versions - see
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161915/change-password-on-a-luks-filesystem-without-knowing-the-password  and https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1543373 for how to do it with LUKS1.  

I double checked and could not make it work with the current version of LUKS.